# Sports Recent History

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Fiddle example below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75561/1

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `straightred_fixture` (
  `fixtureid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fixturedate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fixturestatus` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fixturematchday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `spectators` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hometeamscore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `awayteamscore` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homegoaldetails` longtext,
  `awaygoaldetails` longtext,
  `hometeamyellowcarddetails` longtext,
  `awayteamyellowcarddetails` longtext,
  `hometeamredcarddetails` longtext,
  `awayteamredcarddetails` longtext,
  `awayteamid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hometeamid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `soccerseasonid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fixtureid`),
  KEY `straightred_fixture_2e879a39` (`awayteamid`),
  KEY `straightred_fixture_bcb6decb` (`hometeamid`),
  KEY `straightred_fixture_d6d641f1` (`soccerseasonid`),
  KEY `straightred_fixture_fixturematchday2_f98c3a75_uniq` (`fixturematchday`),
  CONSTRAINT `D9b896edf0aff4d9b5c00682a8e21ea3` FOREIGN KEY (`fixturematchday`) REFERENCES `straightred_fixturematchday` (`fixturematchdayid`),
  CONSTRAINT `straightr_soccerseasonid_92496b92_fk_straightred_season_seasonid` FOREIGN KEY (`soccerseasonid`) REFERENCES `straightred_season` (`seasonid`),
  CONSTRAINT `straightred_fixtu_awayteamid_3d1961ba_fk_straightred_team_teamid` FOREIGN KEY (`awayteamid`) REFERENCES `straightred_team` (`teamid`),
  CONSTRAINT `straightred_fixtu_hometeamid_6e37e94b_fk_straightred_team_teamid` FOREIGN KEY (`hometeamid`) REFERENCES `straightred_team` (`teamid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

What I would like to achieve using an SQL query, if possible, is that for each team from the teams table to show the previous 2 results as a W, L or D (Won Loss or Draw) and who they played against.  I know a game is finished if the "fixturestatus" is set to "Finished" and to establish the most recent two I can use the "fixturedate" field in desceding order.

The output could be something like:

```
team id    Game 1 Result  Game 1 Opponent     Game 2      Game 2 Opponent
  12         W                 15                D             45
  13         L                 45                L             36
```

Below is the copy of the team table incase it may assist with the answer:

```
CREATE TABLE `straightred_team` (
  `teamid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `teamname` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stadium` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homepageurl` longtext,
  `wikilink` longtext,
  `teamcode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `teamshortname` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currentteam` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teamid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Any help would be great, many thanks, Alan.

Comment: instead of `describe` , best to always do something like `show create table straightred_fixture` for each table

Comment: I will amend the question right away.  Thank you.

Comment: pls post some sample input as well

Comment: data help for those that don't know how to provide it: [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38899464)

Comment: That is genius :)  Can't do this just yet but when I do should I add to this question or create a new question?

Comment: Here we go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75561/1

Comment: @AlanTingey do you need something more about your task?

Comment: Sorry, the real world job got in the way.  yvs, what did you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything can be simply done via sql, and sometimes some stuff should be done in a programming language, but as far as the question does not specify a programming language i provide a couple of helpful views and a query

```
CREATE VIEW united_result AS 
SELECT fixtureid, fixturedate, fixturestatus, hometeamid as team,
awayteamid as opponent, 
(CASE WHEN (hometeamscore-awayteamscore)>0 THEN 'W' 
WHEN (hometeamscore-awayteamscore)<0 THEN 'L' ELSE 'D' END) as result, 
'home' as mstatus
FROM straightred_fixture
UNION
SELECT fixtureid, fixturedate, fixturestatus, awayteamid as team, 
hometeamid as opponent, 
(CASE WHEN (hometeamscore-awayteamscore)<0 THEN 'W' 
WHEN (hometeamscore-awayteamscore)>0 THEN 'L' ELSE 'D' END) as result, 
'away' as mstatus
FROM straightred_fixture;

create or replace view plain_result as select fixtureid, fixturedate, 
team, opponent, result, mstatus 
from united_result where fixturestatus='Finished' order by team asc, 
fixturedate desc;

select 
team, 
group_concat( 
concat(result, ' against ', opponent, ' on ', date_format(fixturedate, '%D %M %Y')) 
order by fixturedate desc separator ' | ') as output 
from plain_result 
where (select count(*)
   from plain_result as p
   where plain_result.team = p.team 
   and p.fixturedate>=plain_result.fixturedate) <= 2
group by team;
```

you can try it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ce8f1/11

Comment: Apologies for slow reply.  This is really helpful :)  thank you.